# Grunt error - cannot find module 'tough cookie'

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs, package.json

I am getting an error and I don't know what to make of it.

Grunt works just fine on my machine, but it is failing on my server. They're both the same OS. And I am thinking that my package.json might have installed a later version of something on my server that broke grunt. But I use the `^` for all of my dependencies, so they should be compatible. Here is the grunt error:

```
Loading "compress.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'
Loading "connect.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-signature'
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'js-yaml'
Loading "jasmine.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'hooker'
Loading "less.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'

/home/jeremy/421_API/node_modules/grunt-contrib-requirejs/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:16208
  /**
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Loading "requirejs.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
Loading "stylus.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'

Running "test" (mochaTest) task

  1)  "before all" hook

  0 passing (172ms)
  1 failing

  1)  "before all" hook:
     Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'tough-cookie'




Fatal error: Cannot find module 'tough-cookie'
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.4",
    "cors": "^2.5.3",
    "express": "~4.12.1",
    "express-session": "^1.10.4",
    "jade": "^1.9.2",
    "method-override": "^2.3.3",
    "mongoose": "^4.0.1",
    "mongoose-lifecycle": "^1.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.5.2",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-http": "^0.2.2",
    "q": "^1.3.0",
    "string": "^3.1.1",
    "validator": "^3.37.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^2.3.0",
    "execSync": "^1.0.2",
    "forever": "^0.14.1",
    "grunt": "latest",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "^0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "^0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-handlebars": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jade": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^0.6.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^0.11.4",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "^0.3.3",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.7.4",
    "grunt-contrib-stylus": "^0.15.1",
    "grunt-contrib-symlink": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-yuidoc": "^0.5.2",
    "grunt-mocha": "^0.4.12",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.7",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pm2": "0.12.11",
    "supertest": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

and here is my Gruntfile:

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt){
  // Load grunt mocha task
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib');

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Mocha Test
    mochaTest: {
          test: {
            options: {
              reporter: 'list',
              timeout: 2000
            },
            src: ['test/groups.js',
                        'test/doctors.js',
                        'test/patients.js',
                        'test/diet.js',
                        'test/admin.js']
          },
          web_enter: { // fill database for website testing
            options: {
              reporter: 'list',
              timeout: 2000
            },
            src: ['test/web_testing_enter.js']
          },
          web_remove: { // remove data entered for website testing
            options: {
              reporter: 'list',
              timeout: 2000
            },
            src: ['test/web_testing_remove.js']
          }
        }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('we', ['mochaTest:web_enter']);
  grunt.registerTask('wr', ['mochaTest:web_remove']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['mochaTest:test']);
};
```

Comment: Why are you loading all these tasks (all the `grunt-contrib`) when your gruntfile only uses mocha-test?